# Translating Excel Results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Been working on an industrial solution since December.  Narrowed it down to daily 4 variables.

```
Columns of variables        A    B    C    D
Day 1 Results               2    3    2    2
Day 2 Results               2    3    2    3
```

Using the and function, I combine the day to day change into a single number 23222323

I then have a table with all possible outcomes

Lookup Table Of Possible Results In Ascending Order (Expressed as whole numbers)

```
22122212    Fail
23222323    Good
23233333    Poor
33202322    Excellent
33333322    Undetermined
```

I can't figure out how to look up the daily result of a built up number using the formula `A1&B1&C1&D1&A2&B2&C2&D2` to a table of real numbers in order to return the result "Good" in this example.

Comment: Accepted.  I could find a formal way to accept the answer.  If I missed something, please indicate how to formally accept the solution.

Comment: Hey, just click the check mark by my answer (on the left) . You’ll also get some rep yourself for choosing an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1&B1&C1&D1&A2&B2&C2&D2,<lookup_table_range>,2,0)
```

If your `22122212` (for example) is stored as a number in the lookup table you will need to convert the lookup value to a number as well.

```
=VLOOKUP(--(A1&B1&C1&D1&A2&B2&C2&D2),<lookup_table_range>,2,0)
```

Comment: Damn I thought it would work.  It is telling me I entered too many arguments for the function.  When I try to debug using the f button, nothing appears to be out of the ordinary,

Comment: Too many arguments is an odd one. What is the exact formula you're trying to use? (just put it in a comment below)

Comment: =VLOOKUP(A1&B1&C1&D1&A2&B2&C2&D2,H1:I4,H1:H4,2,0)

Comment: You've got the lookup range twice there, try this: `=VLOOKUP(A1&B1&C1&D1&A2&B2&C2&D2,H1:I4,2,0)`

Comment: You are brilliant.  My sincerest thanks!!!!!  You have no idea how long I struggled with this.